# Plugin activation error due to unexpected output

Tags: plugin-development, activation

I am getting the following error when I activate my plugin:

> The plugin generated 22 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

And here's my plugin code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Hello World
*/

    echo "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>";

?>
```

I know we get this error usually when there's some syntax error in the code. I have checked, there are no blank spaces, `\n`, `\t`, `\r` or any kind of special characters at the starting or ending of the file.

I don't understand, this is the most minimalist plugin one could ever create, what's wrong?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I don't get the error if I remove the `echo "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>";` line.

Comment: Have you checked inside your debug.log?

Comment: @Ben I solved it as per the answer given by fuxia. But would you be kind enough to let me know where can I find the debug.log file?

Comment: Here: [WordPress Debug Log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins are loaded before headers are sent. The reason is that you should be able to send your own headers per plugin.

And that's why a main plugin file must not create direct output. Wrap your `echo` code into a function and register that function as a callback for an action that happens later, after the headers are sent.

Comment: Ohh, got it. Sorry, I'm new.. Solved it, and it worked, thanks! I blame the tutorial which I am following..